# Interactive data input app and linking to sever database

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am in process of creating a interactive Employee information App that will Add new data, retrieve old data and update it.
Eventually i will link this app to SQL server to Add and update employee information details to the Employee Address book table

I although get an `wx.App must be created first!` error

```
import wx
import os
app=wx.App()

class AddressBook(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,"Address Book",size=(520,700))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("#95CAE4")
       
        self.title=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"ADDRESS BOOK DATABASE",pos=(120,10))
        self.firstname=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"FirstName",pos=(50,50))
        #self.firstname1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(160,50),size=(100,20))
        self.secondname=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"SecondName",pos=(35,80))
        #self.secondname1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(160,80),size=(100,20))
        self.addressline1=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Address(Line1)",pos=(30,110))
        self.addressline2=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Address(Line2)",pos=(30,140))
        self.addressline3=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Address(Line3)",pos=(30,170))
        self.city=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"City",pos=(85,200))
        self.state=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"State or Province",pos=(20,230))
        self.zip=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Postal(zip)Code",pos=(25,260))
        self.homephe=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"HomePhone",pos=(40,290))
        self.workphe=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"WorkPhone",pos=(45,320))
        self.mobile=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Mobile",pos=(70,350))
        self.email=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Primary Email",pos=(35,380))
        self.email2=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Secondary Email",pos=(20,410))
        self.notes=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Notes",pos=(75,440))

        self.firstname1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,50),size=(170,20))
        self.secondname1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,80),size=(170,20))
        self.addressline11=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,110),size=(250,20))
        self.addressline21=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,140),size=(250,20))
        self.addressline31=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,170),size=(250,20))
        
        self.city1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,200),size=(170,20))
        self.state1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,230),size=(170,20))
        self.zip1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,260),size=(170,20))
        self.homephe1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,290),size=(170,20))
        self.workphe1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,320),size=(170,20))
        self.mobile1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,350),size=(170,20))
        self.email3=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,380),size=(170,20))
        self.email4=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,410),size=(170,20))
        self.notes1=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,"",pos=(130,440),size=(250,100),style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.btn=wx.Button(self.panel,201,"save",pos=(170,570),size=(70,30))
        self.btn1=wx.Button(self.panel,202,"clear all",pos=(80,570),size=(70,30))
        self.btn2=wx.Button(self.panel,203,"retrieve",pos=(260,570),size=(70,30))
        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.retrive,id=203)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.clear,id=202)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.save,id=201)
       
        self.filename="AddressBookDataBase"
        if not os.path.exists(self.filename):
            os.makedirs('AddressBookDataBase')
frame=AddressBook()

app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Centre()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume, the error is related to some IDE that you are running this under.
If you ran it from the command line, I'm guessing it would work.
Traditionally, the creation of `wx.App()` is placed where you will start referencing it and wrapped into a test for this code being called directly.
i.e.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=wx.App()
    frame=AddressBook()
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Centre()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

p.s. `retrieve` not `retrive`